# How to get two slidetoggle working with JQuery

Tags: jquery

Basically I want to get a piece of code to toggle multiple pieces of code whenever they're clicked ,now I'm new to JQuery and I can't seem to get it working .Any bit of help would be great

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#flip").click(function () {
        $("#panel").slideToggle("1000");
    });
});
</script>
```

above is the script,and below is the code I want to have it effect.

```
        <div class = "description">

        <div id="flip">

                dog says how do ?
                <div id="panel">hidden text</div>   
        </div>

                <div id="flip">

                dog says how do ?
                <div id="panel">more hidden text</div>

        </div>
```

The first "panel" will work but the second is dormant.

Comment: html is not code, and html id attributes are meant to be unique. Change the id="panel" to class="panel" and use the jquery class selector $(".panel") instead. Same for the "flip" element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` should be unique, you need to use class instead:

```
<div class="flip">
    dog says how do ?
    <div class="panel">hidden text</div>   
</div>
```

Then you can do:

```
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".panel").slideToggle("1000");
});
```